# Show that the coarsest topology on $\Bbb R$ with respeet to which the linear functions are continuous is also the usual topology $\mathcal{T}_{std}$.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that the coarsest topology on the real line $\Bbb R$ with respeet to which the linear functions $f: \Bbb R \to (\Bbb R,\mathcal{T}_{std})$ defined by $f(x) = ax + b$ where $a, b \in \Bbb R$ are continuous is also the usual topology $\mathcal{T}_{std}$.

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology induced by the linear maps. By definition $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology generated by the subbase $$\mathscr{S}= \bigcup_{i} \{f^{-1}_i(U_i) \mid U_i \in \mathcal{T}_{std}\}$$ and thus it's the coarsest topology we can put on the domain $\Bbb R$. Hence $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{std}$.

Now we need to prove the reverse inclusion i.e $\mathcal{T}_{std} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$. Let $O \in \mathcal{T}$ note that then $O$ is of form $$O=\bigcup_{i}\left(f^{-1}_{i_1}(O_{i_1})  \cap \dots \cap f^{-1}_{i_m}(O_{i_m}) \right).$$

We notice that $$f^{-1}_{i_m}(O_{i_m})=\{x \in \Bbb R \mid ax+b \in O_{i_m} \}$$ but $O_{i_m}$ is some open interval say $(c,d)$, thus $$f^{-1}_{i_m}(O_{i_m})=\{x \in \Bbb R \mid ax+b \in O_{i_m} \}=\{x \in \Bbb R \mid ax+b \in (c,d) \} = (\frac{c-b}{a}, \frac{d-b}{a})$$

so the preimages are themselves open intervals. So if $V \in \mathcal{T}_{std}$, then $V$ must be in $\mathcal{T}$ also?

Comment: The affine functions are continuous when the domain is endowed with the standard topology. On the other hand, if $\tau$ is a topology on $\mathbb R$ such that all affine functions $(\mathbb R, \tau) \to (\mathbb R, \tau_{\mathrm{stan}})$ are continuous, in particular the identity of $\mathbb R$ is continuous and $\tau \supset \tau_{\mathrm{stan}}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{T}_{\text{std}}$ is **one** of the topologies on $\Bbb R$ so that all $f(x)=ax+b$ functions are continuous with codomain $(\Bbb R, \mathcal{T}_{\text{std}})$ so as $\mathcal{T}$ is the *coarsest* such topology, by **definition** $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_{\text{std}}$.

I don't see how your subbase argument yields the same result. I used the definition of $\mathcal{T}$, you used some theorem on how to generate it, not the definition.

The other inclusion follows however from the fact that $\text{id}_{\Bbb R}: (\Bbb R,\mathcal{T}) \to (\Bbb R, \mathcal{T}_{\text{std}})$ must be continuous as we can take $a=1, b=0$ in particular. And this gives $\mathcal{T}_{\text{std}} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ right away, by the definition of continuity.

So no need for any "computations" at all. Just straightforward logic.